# How to automatically set focus to a SlateJS editor inside a react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, slatejs

I am building a custom SlateJS editor to use in a form, utilising the react-hook-form `<Controller>` component.

This mostly works, but two things (I suspect are related) do not:

1. Focus activation via react-hook-form initialFocus, or setFocus from the form context hook
2. Resetting the form value via the form hook reset() method

This is the controller that hooks up the react-hook-form component:

```js
const CustomEditorController = () => {
    const { control } = useFormContext()

    return (
        <Controller
            name='editor'
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <CustomEditor
                    ref={(el: any} => field.ref(el)}
                    name={field.name}
                    value={field.value}
                    onValueChange={field.onChange}
                />
            )}
        />
    )
}
```

The custom editor component looks like this:

```js
const CustomEditor = React.forwardRef<any, TextEditorProps>(
    (name, value, onValueChange }, ref) => {
        const editor: MyEditor = useMemo(() => (withHistory(withReact(createEditor()))), [])

        useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
            focus: () => {
                console.log("set focus via imperative handle");
                ReactEditor.focus(editor);
            },
        }));

        return (
            <Slate
                editor={editor}
                initialValue={value}
                onValueChange={onValueChange}
            >
                <Editable
                    name={name}
                />
            </Slate>
        )
    }
)
```

With other components I have integrated with react-hook-forms, like a custom text input, you can use this `ref` property, and this all works perfectly - it sets focus at the right time, and resets the input value when `reset()` is invoked via the form hook.

But with this SlateJS editor, I can not see how I can use this ref, or otherwise how to propagate the focus/reset calls from the form to the editor.

I have found there is a `ReactEditor.focus(editor)` SlateJS API that can be used, but how to use that in this scenario, and what about reset() as well?

Comment: Where’s your editor prop coming from? It shouldn’t be a global, but it looks like it is. The sample code shows it coming from state https://docs.slatejs.org/libraries/slate-react/react-editor

Comment: Now that you have an instance of the editor, you can call blur on the ref whenever the editor is blurred and focus on the editor whenever the ref is focused, right? Just follow

Comment: That’s what I said - focus on the editor whenever the ref is focused. So whenever RHF calls a method on the ref named focus, you will call focus on the editor instance. For blur I forgot that, in RHF it doesn’t use the ref, there’s a method on the `field` in the controllers render function called onBlur. When the editor is blurred, you will call that method (just like you call onChange method from RHF when the editor is changed)

Comment: I misread, you're right. After I added the focus setter to the ref via the imperative handle it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `CustomEditor` code, explicitly setting focus via  `useImperativeHandle` was the missing piece:

```js
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  focus: () => {
    console.log("set focus via imperative handle");
    ReactEditor.focus(editor);
  },
}));
```

Fully working sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigorous-gould-x3nwxg.